# Why did one of my files in Xcode disappear?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compiler-errors

While I was working on my project I found out that I couldn't run my project anymore because I had this kind of error:

```
Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/andreagualandris/Desktop/Xcode Projecs/InstagramClone/InstagramClone/ViewControllers/SignUpViewController.swift'
```

Basically one of my ViewController files has disappeared. I can still see the name of the viewController listed in the files but the icon is more pale than the other ones: [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzmuw.png)
and when you click on it a system sound forbids you to click on it. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your project does not contain `SignUpViewController.swift`, so if you have this file on your machine then remove this file from project and add it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Click right button on file, choose **`Show in Finder`**

[image]

**If you can find it here:**

- delete reference from this file on the left panel

[image]

---

> Add it again (**you need to choose** `Copy items if needed`, `Create groups`)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Recovered References , and remove the file from there and add the file again with proper reference. Clean the project and build again.[image]